# Is it safe to populate forms with params values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a form to filter records with fields not linked to an AR object. When form is submitted, I want to show records and populate the form with previously entered values so the user can see filtering parameters.
Form example:

```
 = form_tag businesses_path, method: 'get' do
      .field
        = label_tag :title, 'Title'
        = text_field_tag :title, params[:title]
        = button_tag do
            'Submit'
```

I'm thinking of using `params` to populate form inputs but not sure if it's safe? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: store params value in instance variable

Comment: @test What's the benefit of instance variable?

Comment: @leemour the only benefit would be if you want to sanitise it in the controller before it hits the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're dealing with RESTful interfaces with Rails the params hash is in essence the data in the message between the front end (browser) and the back end. It is there to be used to relay data between the user front end and your controller at the back-end. The params hash is one of the most important and versatile tools in RoR.

From the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

> You will probably want to access data sent in by the user or other parameters in your controller actions. There are two kinds of parameters possible in a web application. The first are parameters that are sent as part of the URL, called query string parameters. The query string is everything after "?" in the URL. **The second type of parameter is usually referred to as POST data. This information usually comes from an HTML form which has been filled in by the user. It's called POST data because it can only be sent as part of an HTTP POST request. Rails does not make any distinction between query string parameters and POST parameters, and both are available in the params hash in your controller:**

---

So use the params hash; it is a sound method for caching user input and re-displaying it, as was your question.

**Caveat**

*Of course, if you're displaying from the hash and not the database store itself, you may encounter data synchronization problems.* But as far as your specific question, I'd say use the params hash without a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely fine. Rails will sanitise anything on it's own. Just don't call `params[:title].html_safe` when you printing "raw" user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that params in a instance variable in respective controller action like flowing in controller.

```
def test_action
  @title = params[:title]
end
```

And then set @title as field value as flowing

```
   = text_field_tag :title, @title
```